# CSS RGBA Color code for grayscale image to colorised image

Tags: css, colors, rgb, rgba

I want to create simple hover effect by CCS3 like Default Image is black and white, but when I hover to this image actual colors of this image will be shown.

Please help me

Comment: show some code that you have worked as well as researched

Comment: background-color: rgba(0 0 0 0); i got that one but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a new property `filter` but broswer support is not super deep (See [**http://caniuse.com/css-filters**](http://caniuse.com/css-filters))

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tPsLy/)

**CSS**

```
img {
    -webkit-filter:grayscale(100%);
}

img:hover {
    -webkit-filter:none;
}
```

**Alternative Method**

This requires a wrapping div and a second color background image

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tPsLy/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-g-250-250-8.jpg" alt=""/>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-250-250-8.jpg);
}

img {
    display: block;
}

.wrap img:hover {
    opacity:0;
}
```